# Is it okay to use dynamic variables to access class properties in PHP?

Tags: php

Today, I realised that I could use variables to access property names in a class, i.e. instead of using `$object->foo` I can set a string variable as `$propname="foo"` and then access the property with `$object->$propname`.

Is this method okay to use, or is it possible that I will get unexpected behaviours/errors that I haven't thought of?

Example code:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $a = "Hello world!";
    public $b = "Bye bye!";
}

$obj = new MyClass();

$property = "a";
echo $obj->$property;  // Hello world!

$property = "b";
echo $obj->$property;  // Bye bye!
?>
```

As a note: I want to use this method in my code where I have classes with many properties and I whish to be able to return diff-responses between objects, like `compare_properties($propertyname, $obj1, $obj2)`

Comment: Nothing fundamentally wrong with doing this. We use it in our project for copying properties between objects based on lists of keys.

Comment: The problem of this type of code is maintainability of the code.iI's hard to understand too.
But sometimes it's cleaner to use this.

Comment: It's just a tool. That's something you could be using in the internals of a framework or library, probably not so much in a standard CRUD app.